# Probability the stoplight will be red

Tags: probability

Cycle of a stoplight : green for $90$ seconds, yellow for $10$ seconds, and red for $60$ seconds. What is the probability that the light will be red for a car approaching the light?

Answer (score 4):

$$ \frac{\color{red}{60}}{\color{red}{60} + \color{goldenrod}{10} + \color{green}{90}} $$

Answer (score 1):

If things are reasonably regular,
$${60\over 90 + 10 + 60} = {3\over 8}.$$